# Full border length for span element regardless of text in span element

Tags: html, css

I have this simple html:

```css
.line {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(101, 101, 101);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="line">atque quae quam? Molestias officiis voluptatum distinctio laborum iste temporibus culpa mollitiaatque quae quam? Molestias officiis voluptatum distinctio laborum iste temporibus culpa mollitiaatque quae quam? Molestias officiis voluptatum distinctio laborum iste temporibus culpa mollitia</span>
</div>
```

What I currently have is this:

[image]

But what I'd like is the border to cover the entire length of each line regardless of the text. Something like this:

(Treat the 3 red squiggly lines as 3 straight black lines haha)

[image]

EDIT 1

From the answer provided. I see a double line here..

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use span, you need to separate it like this:

```css
.line {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(101, 101, 101);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="line">atque quae quam? Molestias officiis voluptatum distinctio laborum iste temporibus culpa mollitiaatque</span><span class="line"> quae quam? Molestias officiis voluptatum distinctio laborum iste temporibus culpa mollitiaatque quae</span><span class="line"> quam? Molestias officiis voluptatum distinctio laborum iste temporibus culpa mollitia</span>
</div>
```

But if your willing to use `<p>` tags you can do it like this:

```css
.line {
  line-height: 20px;
  color: #333;
  background-image: 
repeating-linear-gradient(180deg, transparent, transparent 19px, #333 20px);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p class="line">atque quae quam? Molestias officiis voluptatum distinctio laborum iste temporibus culpa mollitiaatque quae quam? Molestias officiis voluptatum distinctio laborum iste temporibus culpa mollitiaatque quae quam? Molestias officiis voluptatum distinctio laborum iste temporibus culpa mollitia</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I think this is it! The p element works!

Answer (score 3):

Your current snippet shows the standard behavior on a span with a border bottom. You can do it with a `span`, but when the word breaks, so do the borders. You can add `word-break: break-all;` to your span, then add the `border-bottom` to the div also so the bottom is always underlined at 100%.

```css
.line {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(101, 101, 101);
  word-break: break-all;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(101, 101, 101);
}
```

```html
<div><span class="line">atque quae quam? Molestias officiis voluptatum distinctio laborum iste temporibus culpa mollitiaatque quae quam? Molestias officiis voluptatum distinctio laborum iste temporibus culpa mollitiaatque quae quam? Molestias officiis voluptatum distinctio laborum iste temporibus culpa mollitia</span>
</div>
```

Solution #2 ~ no double line.

```css
.line {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(101, 101, 101);
  word-break: break-all;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
}

span:after {
  content: "";
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(101, 101, 101);
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div><span class="line">atque quae quam? Molestias officiis voluptatum distinctio laborum iste temporibus culpa mollitiaatque quae quam? Molestias officiis voluptatum distinctio laborum iste temporibus culpa mollitiaatque quae quam? Molestias officiis voluptatum distinctio laborum iste temporibus culpa mollitia</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh sweet, it works but I notice there's like a double line on the last row. Is it possible to get that removed or is this the closest I can get to?

Comment: @Nigel I assume you are using Firefox? As I don't see the double line on Safari or Chrome.

Comment: Im using chrome. I've attached the result in theedit section of the question

Comment: @Nigel Gotcha, see edits for solution #2. That should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks for the help but the first answer by Rei was the one that worked best for me. I still gave you a thumbs up though for helping out!

Comment: @Nigel I appreciate it. For future reference, you shouldn't specify "on span element" in the title if you are willing to accept answers with another element. I could have done it with the p element also, but `spans` are different and this is about the best you can do with what you are trying to accomplish with the span element.

Answer (score 0):

A `span` is an inline element while `div` is a block element.

Block elements are a rectangle and have a border and float properties. Inline elements do not have a border.

You can turn a span into a block element via css using `display:inline-block` / `display:block` property.

Comment: But I need it to be multiline though

Comment: use  property word-break: break-all

Answer (score 0):

As you might know block, p, etc are block level elements (consists 100% width) and span is inline element (consists space whatever it may require).
so you may use below changes for your code,

```css
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

div {
  display: block;
}

.line {
  width: 100%;
  word-break: break-all;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(101, 101, 101);
}
```

```html
<span class="line">atque quae quam? Molestias officiis voluptatum distinctio laborum iste temporibus culpa mollitiaatque quae quam? Molestias officiis voluptatum distinctio laborum iste temporibus culpa mollitiaatque quae quam? Molestias officiis voluptatum distinctio laborum iste temporibus culpa mollitia</span>
```